# Uso correto do termo "Nivelamento"

Tags: significado, português-brasileiro

Observe a frase :

> "Vamos fazer outra aula para fazer o nivelamento dos seus
>   conhecimentos"

**Esta palavra nesse contexto está sendo utilizada de forma correta ?**

Comment: Nunca ouvi, mas não será um uso figurado do significado 2 do Michaelis? http://michaelis.uol.com.br/moderno/portugues/index.php?lingua=portugues-portugues&palavra=nivelar

Comment: Eu acredito que sim , meu instrutor da auto escola disse isso para um aluno , eu achei muito estranho resolvi perguntar aqui rs.

Comment: E sabes exatamente o que ele queria dizer? Consolidar, aumentar os conhecimentos (nivelá-los com uma meta superior qualquer); avaliar os conhecimentos? Seria bom incorporares na pergunta o contexto e tudo o que sabes. Por exemplo, eu cheguei a pensar que houvesse vários alunos, e o professor quisesse pôr os conhecimentos de todos os alunos ao mesmo nível, embora me parecesse uma ideia estranha (seus é um pronome ambíguo; pode ser *seus* se uma só pessoa ou de várias) mas é o significado primário de *nivelar*, pôr tudo ao mesmo nível, uma superfície, por exemplo.

Comment: Levantar o que não se sabe ao nível do que se sabe....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Segundo o dicionário [Michaelis](http://michaelis.uol.com.br/moderno/portugues/definicao/nivelamento%20_1008677.html):

> **nivelamento**
>
> ni.ve.la.men.to
>
> sm (nivelar+mento2) 1 Ação ou efeito de nivelar. 2 Ação ou efeito de igualar >as fortunas ou as condições sociais. 3 Traçado das curvas de nível de uma >região, a diversas altitudes.

Conforme pode ser observado, a ação de nivelar tem como objetivo igualar, deixar no mesmo nível.

Uma vez que o conhecimento pode ser tido como o quanto você conhece de um determinado assunto ou tema, ou seja, é quantificável, pode sim ser utilizada a expressão "nivelamento de conhecimento".

Afinal, essa expressão indica apenas a necessidade ou intenção de deixar o conhecimento de um determinado grupo "no mesmo nível".

*Nota*: Conforme apontado nos comentários, a pergunta não está muito clara com relação ao seu contexto. Essa resposta leva em consideração a palavra "nivelar" conforme a definição apresentada acima e não no sentido de "medir o nível". Nesse segundo caso, não sei se a sentença apresentada pelo OP pode ser considerada correta sem uma pesquisa mais ampla.

Comment: Essa é a interpretação que resulta do significado primário de *nivelar*, mas ao que parece o instrutor estava a falar com um aluno só. A menos que fosse nivelar os conhecimentos desse aluno com os conhecimentos de outros alunos, mas isso não fica claro na frase.

Comment: Realmente o contexto não está claro na pergunta, mas pessoalmente não vejo muitas outras possibilidades. Acredito ser bastante provável que estava sendo feita uma comparação entre diferentes alunos. Você consegue pensar em muitos outros cenários?

Comment: Eu entendi como "avaliação dos seus conhecimentos", caso em que seria "nivelar" com o sentido de "medir o nível".

Comment: sim, ele quer fazer a medição do seu nível de conhecimento; pois não seria possível ele elevar o nível do seu conhecimento após uma aula considerando que já ocorreram outras.

Comment: Obrigado pela sugestão @Artefacto. Creio que raras vezes vi "nivelar" no sentido de "medir o nível" (ao menos em PT_br), mas entendi o seu ponto de vista e do Jacinto. Vou incluir uma nota na minha resposta

Comment: Pode usar como exemplo um pedreiro usando uma ferramenta chamada de nível para nivelar uma estrutura, ou seja, para verificar o nível, medi-lo.

Comment: James, há em princípio a possibilidade de concluir que não se percebe bem o uso de *nivelamento* naquela frase. Se achas que o uso razoável de *nivelar* é para significar pôr vários alunos ao mesmo nível, e que não parece ser esse o caso (o autor da pergunta diz num comentário que o instrutor se dirigia a um aluno), a conclusão pode ser sempre que a frase não se compreende bem. Também nunca vi *nivelar* significando 'medir o nível'. Ainda pensei que o uso de *nivelar* na frase fosse um brasileirismo, mas se a nossa interpretação é a mesma, e o autor da pergunta também acha estranho...